# How to extract string inside single quotes in PL/SQL using regex or any other method

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to get string present inside single quotes in PL/SQL, either using regex or any other method whichever works.

```
example: 'He is my uncle's son.and he is a programmer' 
output: He is my uncle's son.and he is a programmer
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Considered the use of `trim(<your_text>,'''')`? And if you're on an older version `ltrim(rtrim(<your_text>,''''),'''')`?

Comment: What about a string like 'a single quote '' '? What should the result be? Also, can you have strings like 'here starts the quoted part: '' QUOTED '''?

Comment: in Oracle when we want to put a single quote in a string  then we write it like (' I am going to see "The Palace" ') so the expected output is ( I am going to see 'The Palace'  ) so My requirement is also same I just want to get in the same way.

Comment: Could your string contain a substring that contains a single quote that you would want to preserve?  Like: 'Mr. O'Brien was his name'?

Comment: @Gary_W : Yes it should be preserved.

Comment: For a better answer and to make it easier to help you, you should edit your original post to include sample strings of what the possible data could look like.  Embedded quotes, the string at the start with characters following, at the end, etc.  Use real data examples if possible for the best accuracy.  Show what you've already tried as well.

Comment: My requirement is, I need to convert string into ASCII value but not special characters. so suppose my variable\column has a string value stored in it then I need to convert all the word into ASCII but I don't want to covert ' quote into ASCII..thats why I am looking for a function which can check if any string is present inside single quotes. In my case, I am considering a complete sentence as a string.

Comment: I wonder if you solved the issue. Did you try `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('''He is my uncle''s son.and he is a programmer''', '''(.*)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Result FROM DUAL`?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use Replace function..

`select replace ('<some text here>',chr(39)) from dual;`

example `select replace (q'[this is ' having' mult'iple ' quotes'']',chr(39)), q'[this is ' having' mult'iple ' quotes'']' original_text from dual;`

output will be :

> this is  having multiple  quotes

This will remove all the single quotes in the string.

If you want to remove double quotes then user chr(34).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to remove single quotes I want the string which is inside single quote without removing single quotes then that string will be sent inside a loop.

Comment: The single quotes in the column will not be removed... The function will return the string by removing single quote...